# importing h5py for python Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have ARCGIS 10.2 . When we install this software, python 2.7.3 (on win32) is also installed which we can develop the software by python and by arcpy module. I want to add h5py to it's library. My windows is 64 bit and I downloaded both hy5py 32 and 64 bit and copied them to the Lib folder.  When I open IDLE an try to import it, I encounter with the following error:

> "ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling".

I also copied six. and I think the problem is with numpy. I replaced the numpy from anaconda(numpy 1.9) with numpy in ARCGIS python Library. Then I could import h5py but I could not open arcpy.

I really appreciate for your help

Comment: Is your version of Python 64-bit?  Just because your version of Windows is 64-bit doesn't mean you (or ArcGIS) installed a 64-bit Python.

Comment: Given that error message - have you tried "recompiling" (and/or re-installing) "numpy" yet?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the NumPy that came with your system was built one way, with one version, then you "installed" (by copying) h5py which was built another way, either with a different version or different options for NumPy.

To fix this, you should try building h5py yourself, which you can do by downloading the Source from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/h5py/2.5.0

Or perhaps easier, consider using Pandas.  It can also read and write hdf5 files (though perhaps with fewer arcane features), and it's quite likely that someone has already provided a package for Pandas which is compatible with your existing installation.